# IF inside WHILE with database result not working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop, fetch

I have a simple ticket sale registration system with 6 types of tickets and 3 different "physical" sales locations. Each order is inserted as a row in the database and stores the amount of each type of ticket along with the sale location, total cost and a datetime timestamp.

I want to display the total amount of each ticket type, that was sold within a given time frame along with the total cost of those tickets. I also want to filter the results based on sale location.

This is my db query:

```
"SELECT SUM(ticketType1), SUM(ticketType2), SUM(ticketType3), 
        SUM(ticketType4), SUM(ticketType5), SUM(ticketType6), 
        SUM(cost), saleLocation 
 FROM `orders` 
 WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-07-10 07:00:01' 
            AND '2018-07-11 07:00:00'"
```

Then I display it in a HTML table row:

```
<?php 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["saleLocation"] == 'location1') { ?>
        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo $row["SUM(ticketType1)"] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo $row["SUM(ticketType2)"] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo $row["SUM(ticketType3)"] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo $row["SUM(ticketType4)"] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo $row["SUM(ticketType5)"] ?>
        </div>   

        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo $row["SUM(ticketType6)"] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="cell">
            <?php echo number_format($row["SUM(cost)"], 0, "", "."); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } //end if

 } // end while
?>
```

It works, but I'm trying to use an IF statement inside the WHILE loop to filter the result based on location, but the IF statement doesn't appear to have any effect and instead it displays the results from all 3 locations.
I know I can easily modify the query to achieve this, but I would rather not do that in this specific case.

I'm guessing that the problem still lies within the query, though?

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the dump of your query results, I can only suggest adding a `GROUP BY saleLocation` condition to your SQL query.

Comment: SUM is an aggregation function.  Without a group by, you'll be summing all matching rows.

Comment: I think you are looking for a `switch … case …` statement, considering you don't want to change your query (Which would be the most straightforward approach)

Comment: GROUP BY seems to do the trick! Thanks for helping out a noob!

Comment: Quick follow-up...when I want to display the statistics from the other two locations, I can't use the same WHILE loop and just change the IF statement condition inside, right? 
For example: if($row["saleLocation"] == 'location2') {...}
I tried that, and it doesn't seem to output anything.

Comment: @Aspargeus Again, a bit hard to advise when we cannot see your data. Tip: dump the query data before attempting to loop through the results. You should then see what you are dealing with.

Comment: I used MYSQLI_DATA_SEEK() to set the result pointer back to 0 and then I loop through the result again. The only issue I have now is that I have to echo some result, where I used GROUP BY on the query. Is there a way to "un-group" it in PHP?